# Datatables draw length menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) and I want to draw the length menu out the table as I did it for the global search :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myInputTextField">
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function(){
   myTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})
```

It is possible to do that with the length menu ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by custom pagelength selectbox handler. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823409/datatables-draw-length-menu/32823971#32823971) for further details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/ebRXw/753/)

Yes you can use custom page size handler for datatable by creating a selectbox for row size and add an onchange handler like below.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="pageSize">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
var myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
});
    
$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function(){
    myTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
});
    
$('#pageSize').on('change', function(){
    myTable.page.len( $(this).val() ).draw();
});
```

Comment: Wow awesome ! Thanks a lot